# Unable to get Image Validation via recaptcha

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I have incorporated Google ReCaptcha in my angular project on the client side and it was working fine. I have not changed anything but now I am unable to get image validation dialog box like I used to get before.

Now when I check on "I am not a robot" It verifies directly without asking for image validation and I am able to get the response string from Google API.

Is this behaviour is expected? and what can I do if I want Image validation after checking on "I am not a robot"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out when I tried in another browser it asked me for image validation because after testing many times and verifying by my server, recaptcha does not ask for image validation.